# A message box won't appear when using an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a message box for password validation when clicking on an input type password field. i want the message box to show as soon as i click on the password field.

So far, if i run the page and click on the password input field, i would have to click in, click out then click in again just for the message box to appear. I can't really pinpoint the error here since im fairly new to Javascript and HTML.

I am using visual studio code for the IDE and it doesnt appear to show any errors when i run so it has to be an internal issue.

my code is :

```
function getPassword() {    
            var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
            var number = document.getElementById("number");
            var length = document.getElementById("length");

            // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
        myInput.onfocus = function() {
        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";

}   

 // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

the input type code is as follows:

```
<label for="psw"><b>Password:</b></label> <br>
<input id = "psw" name="psw" type="password" onblur=" getPassword();"/> <br>


<input type="button" value="check password" class="checkpsw">
```

My CSS code is :

```
input {
width: 50%;
padding: 6px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-bottom: 16px;


}
  input[type=radio]{
    position:absolute;
    line-height: 2px;
    
  }
  input[type=checkbox]{
    position:absolute;
    line-height: 2px;
  }
  /* Style the button */
  input[type=button] {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
  }
  .checkpsw {
    background-color: #0fabb6;
    color: white;
  }
  /* Style the container for inputs */
  .container {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  /* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
  #message {
    display:none;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:50%;
  }
  
  #message p {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  /* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
  .valid {
    color: green;
  }
  
  .valid:before {
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
    content: "\2714";
  }
  
  /* Add a red text color and an "x" icon when the requirements are wrong */
  .invalid {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .invalid:before {
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
    content: "\2716";
  }
```

Comment: What does `.onfocus = ...` do? Where is that line located? And why might this be a problem?

Comment: Clicking on textbox and firing validation is just a bad idea. For validations in JS, you can use 'onblur' event which fires when the focus is lost from the textbox or 'onkeyup' event fires when user releases a key.

Comment: @Andreas It is located within the <script> tag within the <body> tag. There is alot of other functions i used for different inputs so i didn't bother putting them in to avoid confusion. The .onfocus event is supposed to show the message box basically supposed to solve my problem here. I placed a comment incase you didn't notice.

Comment: @Andreas also would like to mention the function block i used is placed within the HTML file, i didn't create an external javascript file for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  **myInput.onfocus = function()** outside of the getPassword function block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code in this way. It will solve your problem. Basically, when you go to the password field it will be `focus` So anything you want to do at that time. You can do like if you want to change the border color on the focus you can do it as well.

```
// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}
function getPassword() {    
            var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
            var number = document.getElementById("number");
            var length = document.getElementById("length");       
 // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

Comment: the .onfocus event has to be within the getPassword function inorder for the "myInput" variable to be identified. I modified it the same way you adviced me to do but it just completed removed the event because the variable "myInput" was not identified. atleast what i believe. Maybe i should try using an external file for javascript?

Comment: besides that, i am strongly leaning on my <input> tag code is where the problem is. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: or it might as well be the CSS code.